# CRTP and double inheritance

Tags: java

I have the following sets of classes:

```
public abstract class GSObject<T extends GSObject<T>> {
    public abstract boolean matches(String toMatch);
    //Other functions
    public static <T extends GSObject<T>> T findMatch(List<T> objects, String toMatch){
        //Code that iterates through the list, seeing if one matches;
    }
}

public abstract class Phrase extends GSObject<Phrase> {
    //More code
}
public class Request extends Phrase{
    @Override
    public boolean matches(String toMatch){
        //Implementation of matches()
    }
}
```

Running the following command: `Request.findMatch(allRequests,chat);` gives the following error:
`Bound mismatch: The generic method findMatch(List<T>, String) of type GSObject<T> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Request>, String). The inferred type Request is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends GSObject<T>>`

If I do `Phrase.findMatch(allPhrases, chat);` it does not throw an error, meaning that this has to do with double inheritance.  Do I have to write another static function that works with a Class that extends a Class that extends GSObject?

I've looked into making GSObject an interface, but it has some classes that I would like to define (not abstractly) in the class.

Is there something I am missing (in any of the three classes), or do I need to create an interface that defines the function `matches()` (What I am trying to avoid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make `Phrase` generic in the same way that `GSObject` is:

```
public abstract class Phrase<T extends Phrase> extends GSObject<T> {

public class Request extends Phrase<Request> {
```

This way, `Request` extends `GSObject<Request>` (unlike in your code, where `Request` extends `GSObject<Phrase>`).

Another option might be to decouple some of these dependent types by using wildcards, e.g. by one of these:

```
    public static <T extends GSObject<T>> T findMatch(List<? extends T> objects, String toMatch){

    public static <U extends GSObject<?>> U findMatch(List<U> objects, String toMatch){
```

though this can be tricky to get right. Note that with this approach, `Request` will still advertise that it can handle any `List<? extends Phrase>`, so you lose some of the benefit of the static type system. (In other words, these versions make your classes more permissive than they're really supposed to be.)

A third option is to do both of the above. It does make sense, after all, for `Request.findMatch` to take a `List<? extends Request>`.

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to know which of these makes most sense for your case.

Comment: The second static function was what I needed.  Thanks!